# How to insert a decimal number with Diesel's PgNumeric type?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am stumped as to how to use the `PgNumeric` type for decimal numbers. I noticed in the [tests](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/9c5fec63c081ac14ed920f18bb6216d6b786f0a7/diesel_tests/tests/types.rs) that `1.0` and `-31.0` were inserted into a table using the following instances:

```
PgNumeric::Positive { weight: 0, scale: 1, digits: vec![1] }
```

and

```
PgNumeric::Negative  {weight: 0, scale: 1, digits: vec![31] }
```

I can't seem to figure out how to insert a value with digits to the right of the decimal (like `5.4321`) into a table.

Comment: Getting Diesel to do anything that I want it to do is... challenging. Are you sure you need to use the object directly instead of something like `"1.0::numeric"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: `PgNumeric::Positive { weight: 0, scale: 4, digits: [5, 4321] }`

More examples:

```
// 9.87654321::numeric
PgNumeric::Positive { weight: 0, scale: 8, digits: [9, 8765, 4321] }

// 12345.6789::numeric
PgNumeric::Positive { weight: 1, scale: 4, digits: [1, 2345, 6789] }

// 100000000.000000002::numeric
PgNumeric::Positive { weight: 2, scale: 9, digits: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2000] }

// 0.3::numeric
PgNumeric::Positive { weight: -1, scale: 1, digits: [3000] }
```

It looks as if the algorithm is:

1. Group your number into chunks of 4 digits starting at the decimal point and working outward. These are the **digits**.
2. Count the number of *chunks* needed to represent the integral part and subtract one. This is the **weight**.
3. Count the number of *digits* needed to represent the fractional part. This is the **scale**.

### Test harness

Here's the code I am playing with, extracted from the tests:

```
extern crate diesel;

use diesel::*;
use diesel::types::*;

use diesel::pg::data_types::PgNumeric;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;

 type PgBackend = <PgConnection as Connection>::Backend;

fn main() {
    let query = "100000000.000000002::numeric";
    let expected_value = PgNumeric::Negative {
        digits: vec![31],
        weight: 0,
        scale: 1,
    };
    assert_eq!(expected_value, query_single_value::<Numeric, PgNumeric>(query));
}

fn query_single_value<T, U: Queryable<T, PgBackend>>(sql_str: &str) -> U
    where PgBackend: HasSqlType<T>,
{
    use diesel::expression::dsl::sql;
    let connection = connection();
    select(sql::<T>(sql_str)).first(&connection).unwrap()
}

fn connection() -> PgConnection {
    let result = connection_without_transaction();
    result.begin_test_transaction().unwrap();
    result
}

fn connection_without_transaction() -> PgConnection {
    let connection_url = "postgres://localhost/some_db";
    ::diesel::pg::PgConnection::establish(&connection_url).unwrap()
}
```

### Potentially useful background information

From the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html):

> The **scale** of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. The **precision** of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point. So the number 23.5141 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4.

However, the [Postgres code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2numeric_8c_source.html) says:

```cpp
/*
 * In the NumericShort format, the remaining 14 bits of the header word
 * (n_short.n_header) are allocated as follows: 1 for sign (positive or
 * negative), 6 for dynamic scale, and 7 for weight.  In practice, most
 * commonly-encountered values can be represented this way.
 *
 * In the NumericLong format, the remaining 14 bits of the header word
 * (n_long.n_sign_dscale) represent the display scale; and the weight is
 * stored separately in n_weight.
 */
```

Comment: Just wanted to add onto this and mention that `PgNumeric` is not really designed to be used directly by users. It's instead the direct representation of how it's stored in PG. This is similar to our `PgTimestamp` type, which our higher level impls are built on, but users are meant to use `chrono::NaiveDateTime` or `std::time::SystemTime` instead. The difference being that we don't have a higher level thing that we serialize to instead. Happy to add if there's a reasonable bigdecimal crate to work with.